# create a background ssh tunnel in ruby

Tags: ruby, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

My oracle db is only accessable via a jumpoff server and is load balanced. As a result I run the following background tunnel command in bash:

```
ssh ${jumpoffUser}@${jumpoffIp} -L1521:ont-db01-vip:1521 -L1522:ont-db02-vip:1521 -fN
```

Before I run my commands on the db using sqlplus like so:

```
sqlplus #{@sqlUsername}/#{@sqlPassword}@'#{@sqlUrl}' @scripts/populateASDB.sql
```

This all works fine.

Now I want to rubisize this procedure.

In looking up the documentation on ruby I could not find how to put the tunnel in the background (which would be my preference) but I found documentation on local port forwarding which I thought would emulate the above tunnel and subsequent sqlplus command.

Here is my code:

```
Net::SSH.start( @jumpoffIp, @jumpoffUser ) do |session|
  session.forward.local( 1521, 'ont-db01-vip', 1521 )
  session.forward.local( 1522, 'ont-db02-vip', 1521 )
  puts "About to populateDB"
  res = %x[sqlplus #{@sqlUsername}/#{@sqlPassword}@'#{@sqlUrl}' @scripts/populateASDB.sql > output.txt]
  puts "populateDb output #{res}"
  session.loop
end
```

When I run the above I get the line "About to populateDB" but it hangs on the actual running of the sqlplus command. Is there something wrong with my port forwarding code or how do I put the following:

```
ssh ${jumpoffUser}@${jumpoffIp} -L1521:ont-db01-vip:1521 -L1522:ont-db02-vip:1521 -fN
```

into ruby code?

A

Comment: https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-4.html#s1 ⇐ why do you expect that the command you execute in the subshell of _running ruby process_ is aware of SSH tunnel you’ve just established?

Comment: the tunnel should bind the ports on my machine to the ports on the db servers via the tunnel through the jumpoff. This works in bash. then a call to localhost:1521 goes seemlessly to ont-db01-vip:1521 and a call to localhost:1522 goes seemlessly to ont-db02-vip:1521

Comment: the subshell is working off my machine which should have the port bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this gem: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh-gateway/

```
require 'net/ssh/gateway'

gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(@jumpoffIp, @jumpoffUser)
gateway.open('ont-db01-vip', 1521, 1521)
gateway.open('ont-db02-vip', 1521, 1521)

res = %x[sqlplus #{@sqlUsername}/#{@sqlPassword}@'#{@sqlUrl}' @scripts/populateASDB.sql > output.txt]
puts "populateDb output #{res}"

gateway.shutdown!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

1)  You need to use 'session.loop { true }' so that the session actually loops

2)  You don't start looping the session until your sqlplus command is done, but the sqlplus needs the session looping (the forwarding to be up).

So I suggest creating a background thread using Thread.new and then killing the thread once sqlplus is done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David's answer, I came up with the following:

```
Net::SSH.start(ip_addr, 'user') do |session|
session.forward.local( 9090, 'localhost', 9090 )
  # Need to run the event loop in the background for SSH callbacks to work
  t = Thread.new {
    session.loop { true }
  }
  commands.each  do | command |
    command.call(9090)
  end

  Thread.kill(t)
end
```